# Toggling hidden tooltips using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've had this question for a while, and I can't figure out how to make a tooltip toggle. In websites, there is sometimes a tutorial involving tooltips that explain the functionality of the website or how to use it. I have been trying to do this on my own website

```
<div title = "This is the tutorial!" data-toggle = "tooltip"></div>
```

So I made a tooltip, yet I can't figure out how to make it tooltip without hovering... Is there a specific attribute I could toggle on the div to make the tooltips appear without the user hovering over the div? Thanks!
(Tooltips are built-in HTML ones. On my website I'm using the additional bootstrap template to make them look better.)

RECAP: What I'm trying to achieve is a tooltip that can show whenever a certain function is run and hide when another is run. I cannot figure this out, as all the examples on other websites require the user to hover or click a button or some other action.

Comment: If you are using a framework like boostrap, they have built-in tooltips (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) and their bigger cousins: popovers (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) - otherwise, you can look at their code and how they did it

Comment: Also, remember these are 'opt-in' items - meaning, you need to enable them yourself - if you are using bootstrap, I'll provide a more complete answer (I don't want to add an answer about bootstrap if you are not using it)

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap and the native tooltip feature. I'm trying to get the hidden tooltip to show up without hovering. I am willing to use JQuery and Bootstrap to get this done.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltips in bootstrap are 'opt-in' items - meaning, you need to enable them yourself -

See below:

**UPDATE**

To always show tooltips: trigger the tooltips manually at page load time, see updated code below

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mydiv').tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  });

  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $('#mydiv').tooltip('toggle');
  });
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Click to show Tooltip</button>


<hr/>
<div id="mydiv" title="This is the tutorial!" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">tooltip here?</div>
```

Comment: Again, this isn't what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to get the tooltips to enable automatically- Without the user doing anything. This snippet uses bootstrap (Gotta love it, amazing) and I am using that. I know how to use the tooltips, yet I only know how to toggle them when a user hovers over it. For example, a function called showTooltip that when runned, will show a tooltip on a certain element. So far, all I've been given is samples that require the user to hover. I want the tooltips to hide with the alternate function hideTooltip. I can't seem to figure this out myself...

Comment: So do you mean to show the tooltips always? (not just on hover?)

Comment: Can you do this on a specific element? This triggers all of the tooltips. Still a great answer though :D. Cleared a lot of confusion. EDIT: figured it out, amazing answer!

Comment: updated answer - for a given element, use the target selector

Answer (score 1):

first give the div an id or class:

`<div id='tutorial1' title = "This is the tutorial!" data-toggle = "tooltip"></div>`

then attach a mouseover/mouseout event to that which shows/hides it:

```
$('#id_of_thing_you_hover')..mouseover(function () {
    $('#tutorial1').show();
  })
  .mouseout(function () {
    $('#tutorial1').hide();
  });
```

The `.hide()` and `.show()` jQuery functions simply toggle the element's `display` property

Comment: I may have worded myself wrongly. I want the _popup_ to toggle, not the div.

Comment: well you didn't share the popup code so it's kind of difficult to share but you can EASILY alter the code I've provided to do that. change `id_of_thing_you_hover` to `tutorial1` and then do the show and hide on your popup's id

Comment: There is no popup code... This is using the native popup feature using data-toggle = "tooltip"... You do understand that, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this.

Using JQuery UI (The examples should show you that you can do something real quick. https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

You can either use custom Javascript as below

```
var div = document.querySelector('#[yourdivId]');
div.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    var tooltip = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-toggle"));
    tooltip.classList.remove("[yourHiddenClassName]");
})
div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    var tooltip = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-toggle"));
    tooltip.classList.add("[yourHiddenClassName]");
})
```

or equivalent JQuery like below

```
$("#[yourdivId]").mouseenter(function() {
    var tooltipId = this.data("toggle");
    $("#" + tooltipId).show();
})
.mouseleave(function() {
     var tooltipId = this.data("toggle");
     $("#" + tooltipId).hide();
});
```